# Get position of a child according to the screen, not according to the parent, in AndEngine

Tags: entity, andengine, sprite

I am working on AndEngine GLES2
I have an entity in the scene which have almost 24 children (Sprites) attached to it in different positions.I have made a function which moves the entity from one position to another.Whenever i try to get position of children it returns me the same position as it was in the beginning because it returns the position according to the parent(Entity).As you can see in the example below.

```
Entity myEntity = new Entity();
for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size();i++)
{
    myEntity.attachChild(arraylist.get(i));
}
Log.i("MyLog","Y Position of one child "+arraylist.get(4).getY());//Assume it 231
Log.i("MyLog","Y Position of Entity "+myEntity.getY());//Assume it 0
myEntity.setPosition(0,200);
Log.i("MyLog","Y Position of one child "+arraylist.get(4).getY());//it will return 231
```

It will return the same position as it was in the beginning. I want to get the position of this child according to the screen. I want it to be 431 now as it has moved 200 pixels down on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use the `convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(final float pX, final float pY)` function for example:
`myEntity.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(arrayList.get(4).getX(),arrayList.get(4).getY())` which will return a float array that has a x and y position according to the scene the entity is attached to.